# How can I replace HTML content and avoid replacing java scripts and element and attribute names in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a task to convert all output text from Latin script to Cyrillic script. Complete HTML is first calculated and then printed to browser. I know I can't just replace each letter from Latin to Cyrillic cause it will damage HTML, and to run letter by letter will be very slow. Is there any faster way to do that?

replacing function is simple:

```
str_replace(['A','B','C',...],['А','Б','Ц',...],$outputString);
```

but this will destroy HTML. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "damage HTML" or "destroy HTML"? It sounds more like a charset issue.

Comment: to avoid translating <html> to <хтмл>

Comment: If you need to convert *all* the output then your current function is the solution. If you want to preserve metadata such as URL names, variable names, CSS names, etc and only modify the textual content then you only want to change *some* of the output.

Comment: @symcbean "All output text" HTML is not logically text, despite it being a word salad.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is hard. Instead of solving the problem as asked, I will provide some

## Outside the box solutions

### CSS

#### `@font-face`

You could use a custom font. Simply insert a [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face) directive somewhere in your stylesheet, and provide a font that has the Cyrillic glyphs in place of the ASCII characters. You can create such a font using your favourite font editor; I recommend FontForge.

This has the downside that text that is copied and pasted will appear as Latin, not Cyrillic, script, and also on older browsers the Cyrillic will not be shown.

### JavaScript

#### Recurse and `String.prototype.replace`

You could use JavaScript to perform this find / replace on all of the text nodes *after* the browser has parsed the HTML.

This has the downside of showing the Latin characters briefly before they are replaced by the JavaScript, but copying and pasting should work.

Demonstration:

```js
(function(){
  function makeTextCyrillic(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace('A', 'А').replace('B', 'Б').replace('C', 'Ц');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i += 1) {
      makeTextCyrillic(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    makeTextCyrillic(document.documentElement);
  });
})();
```

```html
<h1>CYRILLIC TEXT</h1>
<p>
  THIS TEXT IS IN A CYRILLIC SCRIPT, BUT IS ACTUALLY ENGLISH TEXT!
</p>
<p>
  ISN'T THAT STRANGE?
</p>
```

### XSLT

#### `xsl:character-map`

XSLT is CSS for XML; it lets you change the actual content of any document, so long as it is valid XML.

Using a stylesheet like this (WARNING: FAULTY - WILL REPLACE INSIDE `<script>` and `<style>` TAGS!):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:character-map name="latin2cyrillic">
       <xsl:output-character character="A" string="А"/>   
       <xsl:output-character character="B" string="Б"/>
       <xsl:output-character character="C" string='Ц'/>
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:output use-character-maps="latin2cyrillic" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

all instances of a single character can be replaced by a string of any number of characters. In this case, a 1 to 1 substitution can be performed.

Usually you would add a directive to the top of the XHTML page that told the browser to process it with this stylesheet, but happily you can do that on the server with PHP's [`XSLTProcessor`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) class.

This has the downside of requiring your original document to be a valid XHTML document, which you can test with [W3's XHTML validator](https://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Well, it is not all about output, there is title head tag, titles and alts attributes, etc.

Comment: @ВојинПетровић In which case you'll probably like my third solution, which I'm writing up at the moment.

Comment: @ВојинПетровић Is this solution satisfactory?

Comment: As I can see on server there is no XSL extension for PHP, and I do not have access to root...

Comment: @ВојинПетровић You could get the client to process the XSL if you make the XSLT file accessible by the client... But I just realised that this will also replace inside `<script>` tags. :-(

Comment: Even the portal I'm creating is very huge with lot lot lot of scripts for creating output, it was easier to convert text as needed while creating output content and more safe and precise... I have abandoned this idea for "global change"

Comment: @ВојинПетровић If you want to help future people who are trying the same thing, you could post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since my task was to change everything that have to be changed - title and  description in head tag, all content including alt/title tags on images and links, some javascript text... looks there is **no other way which is 100% safe** than to convert text prior output, not to be managed after complete html has been formed.

Thanks to guys who tried to help.